# Which branch of math theory could solve the task?

Tags: recurrence-relations, decision-theory, decision-problems

Imagine that we have a value $s_i = f(s_{i-1}, x_{i-1})$, reccurent formula $s_i$ with parameter $x_i$. $x_i$ values depends on $x_0$ and each $x_i$ is calculated in a diffenrent way. I guess it is legitimate to say that $x_i$ is descrete value defined by $x_0$. We know that $s_0 = a$ and $s_n = b$. How to pick $x_0$ so that we get required $s_0$ and $s_n$?

For example: we are invested \$100 to something and want it to be \$1000 in 12 month ($s_0 = 100, s_{11} = 1000$). And we could pick some initial parameter $x_0$ that will define our monthly revenue. And from $x_0$ we could calculate $x_i, i\in{0, ..., 11}$.

I guess it could be from decision theory. Is there any methods that can solve a task of this type?

Comment: Also there is a small question. How to escape $ correctly?

Comment: Perhaps \$ (`\$`) works?

Comment: Tried - didn't work for me. Still making Latex between two $.

Comment: Discrete Mathematics's stream in general.

Comment: `\$` definitely appears to work. See for example: \$ x^2=1 \$ (no latex between the dollar signs)

Comment: Your function is opaque and you did not say how we calculate $x_i$ from $x_0\,.$ There is currently no answer to this question.

Comment: @preferred_anon Ok, you are right, thanks

Comment: @KurtG. Let's say that $s_i = s_{i-1} * (1 + x_{i-1})$. And $x_i = c * x_{i-1} + y_i$. Where $c$ - const and $y_i$ also a set of predefined consts.